# Images not showing in Owl Carousel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have created a Divi child-theme that I am using to customize. I am trying to implement an owl carousel slider for images but for some reason the image isn't displaying. I can see the outline of the box where it should be displaying, so I think it recognizes the path, but I may be wrong. Here is a picture of the problem from my Chrome developer console:

[image]

here is the line of code I am using in my .php file to call this:

```
<div class="clients owl-carousel owl-theme">
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/holoNike.png" alt="nike">
  </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/holoAns.png" alt="Nature">
    </div>
```

It shows an error for the image with alt text because I haven't included that image yet, so the error is expected. Although I am unsure why it only shows the blank image outline for the image I do have (Nike logo), as the path should be correct (when I enter the URL it shows the image as well in my localhost). Any ideas to what may be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Flexbox? If so, owl carousel has been proven to be very troublesome in those scenarios.

Comment: I am using a bootstrap cdn in my child theme.